# How to find standard deviation in Excel faster?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, standard-deviation

I have a huge number of .xls files (originally in .dat) to process and I need to find the standard deviation of some data.

The files I am processing with look as follows:
The first column is year (which starts from 1967 to 1996) and second column is month and third column is day. The fifth column is some data I'm processing with. I want to find the standard deviation of the data in the fifth column by month (i.e. standard deviation of data in Jan from 1967 to 1996,etc.)

I have 40 such files and it's killing me to do it manually. Are there any shortcuts or tricks I can use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pivot table. Then group by Month (month in Row Labels) and Data in Values. Then you just change the way the data is aggregated from default SUM to STDEV. 
[image]

Comment: This is really amazing. Thank you!

Comment: I have 40 files to process, how can I do it even faster?

Comment: I found this solution [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsbdMiruX68) . The code is provided in the link below the video. Just adjust it for your needs.